# Stack Class in R - Something More Concise

Tags: r, data-structures, stack

Does R have a stack that you don't have to code yourself?

Literally, I just want something right out of CS 102.

I wrote the code below, and it works great.  But I'd rather have something else more universal and proven.

Does the language have something?  Or some package of all the usual algorithms, such as queues, trees, etc as well?

```
####################################################################################################
# Stack.R - Implments a generalized stack.  Uses Reference Classes since we need mutability.
####################################################################################################

Stack <- setRefClass("Stack",
     fields = list(
        vStack = "vector",
        nTop = "numeric"
     ),
    methods = list(
        initialize = function() {
            nTop <<- 1
        },
        push = function(nItem) {
            vStack <<- c(vStack, nItem)
            nTop <<- nTop + 1
            vStack[nTop-1]
        },
        pop = function() {
            if (nTop == 1) return(NULL)
            nItem <- vStack[nTop-1]
            nTop <<- nTop - 1
            vStack <<- vStack[1:nTop-1]
            nItem
        },
        top = function() {
            vStack[nTop-1]
        }
    )
)

# StackTest <- function() {
#     
#     say("Starting...")
#     s <- Stack()
#     say(s$push(1), " {push}")
#     say(s$push("Hello"), " {push}")
#     say(s$push(2), " {push}")
#     say(s$push("World"), " {push}")
#     say(s$push(3), " {push}")
#     say(s$top(),   " {top}")
#     say(s$top(),   " {top}")
#     say(s$pop(),   " {pop}")
#     say(s$pop(),   " {pop}")
#     say(s$pop(),   " {pop}")
#     say(s$pop(),   " {pop}")
#     say("Finished.")
#     
# }
# 
# StackTest()
```

Comment: What do you actually want to do?  Making a stack is only useful if there's something you can't achieve more easily with the basic vectorized `R` operators and functions.

Comment: Excellent to ask intent!  I'm not trying to do core data processing here.  More about tracking program behavior.  I want to have timed checkpoints such that I can know when they start and end, such that there are no assumptions about call depth, and such that I want it highly targeted--thus not just things like debug tracing which would be far too verbose.  So I make the call at the top and bottom of any function to trace, and the stack puts the method name and system time on the stack; and pops it when done.

Comment: Well, you might want to insert some `proc.time` and `system.time` calls to do that.

Comment: Thanks to the folks below for the ideas.  I've reviewed them.  But as Martin noted, it just reinforces the point--R doesn't have something native here.  E.g. I just learned Python in the past few months, and stack behavior is right in the notion of a list--that level of ease does not appear to remotely exist in R.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

Not really answering your question, but (a) reference classes seem to do a good job of changing the memory management so there is less copying, but are not necessarily performant compared to other reference-based implementations; and (b) the "copy-and-append" paradigm in `vStack <<- c(vStack, nItem)` scales very poorly. Here's a little ticker function

```
ticker = function(s) {
    i = 0
    t0 = Sys.time()
    while (i < 1000000) {
        s$push(i)
        i <- i + 1
        if (i %% 10000 == 0)
            print(i / as.numeric(Sys.time() - t0)) 
    }
}
```

with throughput starting at 3,800 operations / s falling to 2,700:

```
> ticker(Stack())
[1] 3784.634
[1] 3546.138
[1] 3429.046
[1] 3303.904
[1] 3192.252
[1] 3090.162
[1] 3000.161
[1] 2908.317
[1] 2826.459
[1] 2744.961
^C
```

Here's an incomplete implementation using a local environment

```
s = local({
    v = numeric()
    list(push=function(elt) v <<- c(v, elt),
         val=function() v)
})
```

with much higher initial throughput, and with the limitations of the "copy-and-append" strategy now much more apparent.

```
> ticker(s)
[1] 67933.63
[1] 41231.02
[1] 29095.23
[1] 22347.02
[1] 18274.56
[1] 14007.66
[1] 12436.16
[1] 11122.1
[1] 10034.59
[1] 9123.754
^C
```

Here's a "pre-allocate-and-fill" strategy adopting the same local environment approach implemented as a function call

```
stack <- function(type="numeric", length=1000L) {
    v <- vector(type, length)
    i <- 1L
    list(push=function(elt) {
        if (i == length(v))
            length(v) <<- 1.6 * length(v)
        v[[i]] <<- elt
        i <<- i + 1L
    }, val=function() v[seq_len(i - 1L)])
}
```

and it's improved performance

```
> ticker(stack())
[1] 155448.8
[1] 170315.3
[1] 174391.1
[1] 177424.6
[1] 179275.5
[1] 180605.6
[1] 179693.4
[1] 180258.7
[1] 180681
[1] 181290.1
^C
```

I guess all of this just emphasizes your original point, that you'd like a Stack implementation without re-inventing the wheel, and perhaps also @CarlWhitthoft 's implicit point that you can be better off thinking of algorithms that exploit R's vector operations.

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a 'Containers' package on CRAN that implemented these things, but it seems to have died a few years ago:

ftp://www.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/Containers/index.html

you could check out the old source, maybe resurrect it and take it on as maintainer? Although that might be fun given that a large chunk of it is a java jar file with no obvious source. Which explains why it was pulled. Probably easier to start your own.

Otherwise I struggle to find implementations. I know I wrote a stack class many years ago too.

Answer (score 1):

Now, many years later, there finally **is** a well-supported stack class for R (along with a queue and a map class) in the `r-lib` package
`fastmap`:

https://github.com/r-lib/fastmap